# Cannot print a label to a printer

Tags: java, image, printing, label

I am writing a program to generate labels and to print the labels on a standard printed using label sheets. I can create an image and save it but, I am having problems getting the image to print on the label sheet. It is blank. I can write the image to disk and open the image, it appears to be a valid image. However, no matter what I do I cannot get it to print. I have written a test program to try and print it to no avail. I downloaded an image from the net and was able to print that.

The created label will need to be printed on a label sheet (contains 6 labels from top to bottom). I need to create a label and have it print starting at the desired label on the sheet.

The LabelImage class creates the image for the label. The image has up to 4 digits printed on the left side of the label (rotated 90 degrees clockwise), then some string values. I had to create the digits in a separate image as I could not get them properly rotated in a single image.

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class LabelImage {

    public static final Map <String, Color> ColorMap = new HashMap <> ();

    // Define label size
    public static final int LABEL_WIDTH = 830;
    public static final int LABEL_HALF_WIDTH = LABEL_WIDTH / 2;
    public static final int LABEL_HEIGHT = 190;
    public static final int LABEL_HALF_HEIGHT = LABEL_HEIGHT / 2;

    // Define rectangle to print out digits in for the label
    public static final int LEFT_DIGIT_RECT_TLX = 15;
    public static final int LEFT_DIGIT_RECT_TLY = 30;
    public static final int LEFT_DIGIT_RECT_WIDTH = 80;
    public static final int LEFT_DIGIT_RECT_HEIGHT = (LABEL_HEIGHT - (LEFT_DIGIT_RECT_TLY * 2));
    public static final int LEFT_DIGIT_TLX_OFFSET = -10;
    public static final int LEFT_DIGIT_TLY_OFFSET = 15;

    public static final int LEFT_DIGIT_ROTATE_X = LEFT_DIGIT_RECT_WIDTH / 2;
    public static final int LEFT_DIGIT_ROTATE_Y = LEFT_DIGIT_RECT_TLY + (LEFT_DIGIT_RECT_HEIGHT / 4);
    public static final int LEFT_DIGIT_ROTATE_Y2 = LEFT_DIGIT_ROTATE_Y + (LEFT_DIGIT_RECT_HEIGHT / 2);

    // Create a separate image of the digits, then rotate the image
    public static final int LEFT_DIGIT_TLX = 20;
    public static final int LEFT_DIGIT_TLX2 = (LEFT_DIGIT_RECT_HEIGHT / 2) + LEFT_DIGIT_TLX;
    public static final int LEFT_DIGIT_TLY = (LEFT_DIGIT_RECT_WIDTH - 25);
    public static final int ROTATE_X = 0;
    public static final int ROTATE_Y = 0;

    public static final float DIGIT_FRAME_THICKNESS = 5;

    public static final int CLIENT_ID_X = 380;
    public static final int CLIENT_ID_Y = 30;
    public static final int CLIENT_ID_Y2 = LABEL_HALF_HEIGHT + CLIENT_ID_Y;

    public static final int CLIENT_NAME_X = 450;
    public static final int CLIENT_NAME_Y = 30;
    public static final int CLIENT_NAME_Y2 = LABEL_HALF_HEIGHT + CLIENT_NAME_Y;

    public static final int PROJECT_NAME_X = CLIENT_NAME_X;
    public static final int PROJECT_NAME_Y = 50;
    public static final int PROJECT_NAME_Y2 = LABEL_HALF_HEIGHT + PROJECT_NAME_Y;

    public static final int OTHER_X = CLIENT_ID_X;
    public static final int OTHER_Y = 70;
    public static final int OTHER_Y2 = LABEL_HALF_HEIGHT + OTHER_Y;

    Font normalFont = new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 14);
    Font leftDigitFont = new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 42);



    static {
        ColorMap.put("0", new Color(255, 120, 130, 100));
        ColorMap.put("1", new Color(252, 0, 105, 100));
        ColorMap.put("2", new Color(255, 165, 10, 100));
        ColorMap.put("3", new Color(255, 85, 10, 100));
        ColorMap.put("4", new Color(122, 252, 12, 100));
        ColorMap.put("5", new Color(0, 145, 0, 100));
        ColorMap.put("6", new Color(60, 255, 255, 100));
        ColorMap.put("7", new Color(40, 0, 120, 100));
        ColorMap.put("8", new Color(222, 182, 245, 100));
        ColorMap.put("9", new Color(145, 55, 0, 100));

        ColorMap.put("0", new Color(196, 23, 27, 100));
        ColorMap.put("1", new Color(232, 85, 66, 100));
        ColorMap.put("2", new Color(236, 131, 101, 100));
        ColorMap.put("3", new Color(230, 229, 48, 100));
        ColorMap.put("4", new Color(184, 224, 101, 100));
        ColorMap.put("5", new Color(53, 161, 19, 100));
        ColorMap.put("6", new Color(66, 142, 232, 100));
        ColorMap.put("7", new Color(98, 83, 234, 100));
        ColorMap.put("8", new Color(26, 15, 126, 100));
        ColorMap.put("9", new Color(95, 17, 143, 100));
    }

    /**
     * Prints a digit on the left hand side of the label, rotated 90 degrees 
     * clockwise. At the specified digit location.
     * @param digit the digit to print
     * @param ndx  the index location to print at
     */
    private void printLeftDigit(Graphics2D g2, String digit, int ndx) {

        // find the top-left coordinate of the rectangle
        int tlx = LEFT_DIGIT_RECT_TLX + (LEFT_DIGIT_RECT_WIDTH * ndx);
        int tly = LEFT_DIGIT_RECT_TLY;

        // Draw the colored rectangle
        Color origColor = g2.getColor();
        g2.setColor(ColorMap.get(digit));
        g2.fillRect(tlx, tly, LEFT_DIGIT_RECT_WIDTH, LEFT_DIGIT_RECT_HEIGHT);
        g2.setColor(origColor);

        // Draw a black outline for the box over the rectangle
        Stroke oldStroke = g2.getStroke();
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(DIGIT_FRAME_THICKNESS));
        g2.drawRect(tlx, tly, LEFT_DIGIT_RECT_WIDTH-1, LEFT_DIGIT_RECT_HEIGHT);
        g2.setStroke(oldStroke);

        // Center of digit to rotate around
        int cdx = tlx + LEFT_DIGIT_ROTATE_X;

        // Write the digit in the rectangle
        AffineTransform origTransform = g2.getTransform();
        g2.setFont(leftDigitFont);
        //g2.rotate(Math.PI/25);

        double angle = Math.toRadians(90.0);

        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.rotate(angle, cdx, LEFT_DIGIT_ROTATE_Y);
        g2.drawString(digit, cdx + LEFT_DIGIT_TLX_OFFSET, LEFT_DIGIT_ROTATE_Y + LEFT_DIGIT_TLY_OFFSET);
        g2.setTransform(origTransform);

        //g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g2.rotate(angle, cdx, LEFT_DIGIT_ROTATE_Y2);
        g2.drawString(digit, cdx + LEFT_DIGIT_TLX_OFFSET, LEFT_DIGIT_ROTATE_Y2 + LEFT_DIGIT_TLY_OFFSET);
        g2.setTransform(origTransform);
    }

    /**
     * This method creates a 2nd image for the digits, then rotates the image and puts it 
     * over the label image.
     *
     * @param g2
     * @param digit
     * @param ndx 
     */
    private void printLeftDigit2(Graphics2D g2, String digit, int ndx) {

        // Width is the top to bottom rectangle size
        // height is the left to right rectangle width (because it will be rotated)
        //BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(LEFT_DIGIT_RECT_HEIGHT, LEFT_DIGIT_RECT_WIDTH, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(LEFT_DIGIT_RECT_HEIGHT, LEFT_DIGIT_RECT_WIDTH, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D imageGraphics = image.createGraphics();

        // Fill the rectangle with the expected color
        imageGraphics.setColor(ColorMap.get(digit));
        imageGraphics.fillRect(0, 0, LEFT_DIGIT_RECT_HEIGHT, LEFT_DIGIT_RECT_WIDTH);

        // Draw a black outline for the box over the rectangle
        imageGraphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        Stroke oldStroke = imageGraphics.getStroke();
        imageGraphics.setStroke(new BasicStroke(DIGIT_FRAME_THICKNESS));
        imageGraphics.drawRect(0, 0, LEFT_DIGIT_RECT_HEIGHT, LEFT_DIGIT_RECT_WIDTH);
        imageGraphics.setStroke(oldStroke);

        // Draw the Digits in the rectangle (top-left of digit)
        imageGraphics.setFont(leftDigitFont);
        imageGraphics.drawString(digit, LEFT_DIGIT_TLX, LEFT_DIGIT_TLY);
        imageGraphics.drawString(digit, LEFT_DIGIT_TLX2, LEFT_DIGIT_TLY);
        imageGraphics.dispose();

        // Put the image on the current graphic
        AffineTransform aff = g2.getTransform();
        double theta = Math.toRadians(90.0);
        //AffineTransform rotate = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(theta, rotx, roty);
        //(x,y) = middle of rectangle
        AffineTransform rotate = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(theta, 40, 65);
        //x >0 moves down; <0 moves up
        //y >0: moves left; <0: moves right
        int moveright = 15 - (ndx * LEFT_DIGIT_RECT_WIDTH);
        rotate.translate(10, moveright);
        //g2.drawImage(image, rotate, this);
    }

    public BufferedImage createImageWithText(ClientProject clientProject){

        //ARGB = transparent
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(830, 190,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics g = bufferedImage.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.fillRoundRect(0, 0, LABEL_WIDTH, LABEL_HEIGHT, 10, 10);

        String clientId = String.valueOf(clientProject.getClientId());
        String clientName = clientProject.getClientName();
        String projectName = clientProject.getProjectName();
        String created = "DFC: " + DateUtil.format(clientProject.getCreated(), DateUtil.LABEL_DATE_PATTERN);

        // Setup for drawing to screen
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.setFont(normalFont);
        g.drawLine(0, LABEL_HALF_HEIGHT, LABEL_WIDTH, LABEL_HALF_HEIGHT);

        // write client id on tabs
        String tmp = clientId;
        if (clientId.length() > 4) {
            tmp = tmp.substring(0, 4);
            System.out.println("tmp = " + tmp);
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(tmp);
        sb.reverse();
        for (int ndx=0; ndx < sb.length(); ndx++) {
            try {
                printLeftDigit2((Graphics2D)g, String.valueOf(sb.charAt(ndx)), ndx);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            }
        }

        // Write client id
        g.setFont(normalFont);
        g.drawString(clientId, CLIENT_ID_X, CLIENT_ID_Y);
        g.drawString(clientId, CLIENT_ID_X, CLIENT_ID_Y2);

        // Write Client Name
        g.drawString(clientName, CLIENT_NAME_X, CLIENT_NAME_Y);
        g.drawString(clientName, CLIENT_NAME_X, CLIENT_NAME_Y2);

        // Write Project Name
        g.drawString(projectName, PROJECT_NAME_X, PROJECT_NAME_Y);
        g.drawString(projectName, PROJECT_NAME_X, PROJECT_NAME_Y2);

        // Write created
        g.drawString(created, OTHER_X, OTHER_Y);
        g.drawString(created, OTHER_X, OTHER_Y2);

        return bufferedImage;
    }
}
```

The PrintLabel program is supposed to print the image to the label sheet, but I cannot get it to print the image created by the code above. I had taken this class from somewhere else on the net, and tried to modify it for my purposes.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.Paper;
import java.awt.print.Printable;
import static java.awt.print.Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
import static java.awt.print.Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class PrintLabel {


    protected static double fromCMToPPI(double cm) {            
        return toPPI(cm * 0.393700787);            
    }

    protected static double toPPI(double inch) {            
        return inch * 72d;            
    }

    protected static String dump(Paper paper) {            
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(64);
        sb.append(paper.getWidth()).append("x").append(paper.getHeight())
           .append("/").append(paper.getImageableX()).append("x").
           append(paper.getImageableY()).append(" - ").append(paper
       .getImageableWidth()).append("x").append(paper.getImageableHeight());            
        return sb.toString();            
    }

    protected static String dump(PageFormat pf) {    
        Paper paper = pf.getPaper();            
        return dump(paper);    
    }

    public void process() {

        PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        if (pj.printDialog()) {
            PageFormat pf = pj.defaultPage();
            Paper paper = pf.getPaper();
            double width = fromCMToPPI(20.3);
            double height = fromCMToPPI(25.4);

            paper.setSize(width, height);
            paper.setImageableArea(
                            fromCMToPPI(0.25), 
                            fromCMToPPI(0.5), 
                            width - fromCMToPPI(0.35), 
                            height - fromCMToPPI(1));

            System.out.println("Before- " + dump(paper));
            pf.setOrientation(PageFormat.PORTRAIT);
            pf.setPaper(paper);
            System.out.println("After- " + dump(paper));
            System.out.println("After- " + dump(pf));
            //dump(pf);

            PageFormat validatePage = pj.validatePage(pf);
            System.out.println("Valid- " + dump(validatePage));

            MyPrintable printable = new MyPrintable();
            printable.labels.add(new ClientProject(112, 208, "Taxes", "Tax Refund"));
            printable.determinePageCount();

            pj.setPrintable(printable, pf);

            try {
                pj.print();
            } catch (PrinterException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrintLabel pl = new PrintLabel();
        pl.process();
    }

    public class MyPrintable implements Printable {

        public int startAtLabel = 0;
        public int totalPages = 0;
        public List <ClientProject> labels = new ArrayList <> ();
        private List <ClientProject> printed = new ArrayList <> ();


        /**
         * Determines how many pages to print, there are 6 labels per page. If we
         * start at index 5 (the last one) and there are 2 labels, there are 2
         * pages to print.
         */
        public void determinePageCount() {
            int max = this.startAtLabel + this.labels.size();
            this.totalPages = max / 6;
            if ((max % 6) != 0) {
                this.totalPages++;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) 
                throws PrinterException {

            System.out.println(pageIndex);
            int result = NO_SUCH_PAGE;    
            // first page is index 0, if 1 page max index is 0
            if (pageIndex < this.totalPages) {                    

                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graphics;                    
                System.out.println("[Print] " + dump(pageFormat));                    

                double width = pageFormat.getImageableWidth();
                double height = pageFormat.getImageableHeight();    
                g2d.translate((int) pageFormat.getImageableX(), 
                    (int) pageFormat.getImageableY());
                System.out.printf("wxh = (%fx%f)", width,height);

                // Max of 6 labels per page
                int maxLabelsOnPage = 6;
                if (pageIndex == 0) {
                    maxLabelsOnPage = 6 - startAtLabel;
                }

                // Loop for up to the max number of labels or until we run out 
                // of labels
                for (int labelCnt=0; labelCnt < maxLabelsOnPage; labelCnt++) {

                    // We have run out of labels and there is nothing left to print
                    if (this.labels.isEmpty()) {
                        break;
                    }

                    // Remove the label from the list and add it to the printed list
                    ClientProject cp = this.labels.remove(0);
                    this.printed.add(cp);

                    // Create the image for the label
                    BufferedImage image = null;
                    try {

                        // Create the image for the label
                        LabelImage li = new LabelImage();
                        BufferedImage bi = li.createImageWithText(cp);

                        // Load the label image
                        //image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Consulting\\Development\\JJCPA\\finland.png"));
                        System.out.printf("image %d x %d%n", bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight());

                        // Draw the image at the label offset
                        graphics.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight(), null);

                        // Write to a file to verify the image is valid
                        File outputfile = new File("image.png");
                        ImageIO.write(bi, "png", outputfile);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    }
                }

                result = PAGE_EXISTS;    
            }    
            return result;    
        }
    }
}
```

ClientProject is a simple data structure.

```
public class ClientProject {

    private final SimpleIntegerProperty projectId;
    private final SimpleIntegerProperty clientId;
    private final SimpleStringProperty category;
    private final SimpleStringProperty type;
    private final SimpleStringProperty projectDesc;
    private final SimpleStringProperty projectName;
    private final SimpleStringProperty projectName2;
    private final SimpleStringProperty fileOrBinder;
    private final ObjectProperty <LocalDate> created;
    private final ObjectProperty <LocalDate> destroyed;
```

Comment: That's an awful lot of unnecessary code – can you provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example?

Comment: This is the complete sample program. I have just a test Print:abel program that simply loads an image from a file and prints it, which works. There is something in here in how I am creating my image that the PrintLabel application does not like. I am unable to figure out what it is. Other than removing some of the debug (that was my mistake not getting it all out) there is not much to remove that would leave a functioning program with the issue I am trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error with the logic. I thought I could render a single page easy h time the method was called, until I was done creating an image for each label. 0thus, I tracked which labels I printed. this was wrong. I needed to print a through b labels for index 1 for as many times as index 1 was called, then print the next group of labels each time index 2 was passed, rewriting for this logic solved the problem.